# Class.forName cause classloader moved to tenured generation?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, classloader

I have seen *Class.forName()* causes the tenured generation got filled. I suspect something JVM does internally will move the ClassLoader objects to tenured generation. For example, the following code:

```
public class Test  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (int i=0 ;i<30000;i++) {
            test();
        }
    }
    private static void test() throws Exception {
        MyClassLoader cl = new MyClassLoader();
        Class.forName("java.lang.String", false, cl);
    }
}

public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {}
```

will output gc log:

[GC [DefNew: 512K->64K(576K), 0.0041095 secs] 512K->344K(1984K), 0.0042064 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 576K->64K(576K), 0.0032096 secs] 856K->682K(1984K), 0.0032937 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 575K->63K(576K), 0.0032085 secs] 1194K->1021K(1984K), 0.0033686 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 575K->64K(576K), 0.0025146 secs] 1533K->1359K(1984K), 0.0026305 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 576K->64K(576K), 0.0025942 secs][Tenured: 1634K->166K(1664K), 0.0169541 secs] 1871K->166K(2240K), 0.0197106 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 512K->64K(576K), 0.0019209 secs] 678K->505K(1984K), 0.0020053 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 576K->63K(576K), 0.0022846 secs] 1017K->844K(1984K), 0.0024271 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 575K->63K(576K), 0.0023358 secs] 1356K->1182K(1984K), 0.0024235 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 575K->64K(576K), 0.0025660 secs][Tenured: 1457K->166K(1536K), 0.0136841 secs] 1694K->166K(2112K), 0.0164004 secs]

If change the *Class.forName* to *loadClass*:

```
private static void test() throws Exception {
    MyClassLoader cl = new MyClassLoader();
    cl.loadClass("java.lang.String");
    //Class.forName("java.lang.String", false, cl);
}
```

then gc output will be:

[GC [DefNew: 512K->63K(576K), 0.0028769 secs] 512K->138K(1984K), 0.0029627 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 575K->0K(576K), 0.0009856 secs] 650K->138K(1984K), 0.0010711 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 512K->0K(576K), 0.0006255 secs] 650K->138K(1984K), 0.0007062 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 512K->0K(576K), 0.0002065 secs] 650K->138K(1984K), 0.0002861 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 512K->0K(576K), 0.0001936 secs] 650K->138K(1984K), 0.0002674 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 512K->0K(576K), 0.0002045 secs] 650K->138K(1984K), 0.0002796 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 512K->0K(576K), 0.0001704 secs] 650K->138K(1984K), 0.0002481 secs]
[GC [DefNew: 512K->0K(576K), 0.0002229 secs] 650K->138K(1984K), 0.0003118 secs]

Reproduced in sun jdk1.5 and 1.6. What's happening inside jvm (class load and gc) here?

Thanks.

Comment: For more behavior i noticed, the MyClassLoader objects CAN be gc-ed. But since they fill the tenured generation, it will cause full gc frequently in long time running which is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

You have too small of a sample to really show a definite cause for differences in GC behavior.  First of all, your `MyClassLoader` should not actually load the `java.lang.String` class because it's already present in the boot class loader.  Your ClassLoader objects (and Class objects themselves) should move all the way to the PermGen space, so your guess about them being in the tenured generation is a bit suspect.

Basically, your question "what's going on inside the JVM here" is too generic -- just reading a GC log output doesn't really tell you much since even seemingly trivial differences in code could cause wildly different GC patterns, especially over small test code.

Comment: The ClassLoader objects are in heap, not PermGen.

Comment: I use visualgc tool to monitor the gc, the PermGen is constantly steady, and the Young and Tenured vary repeatedly. Also by analyzing heap dump with IBM HA tool reveals that there are many MyClassLoader objects in heap (though they're eligible for gc). The test code loads "java.lang.String" intentionally to remove any possible outer impact. So basically i just want to know, in such a simple test case by using Class.forName(), what has happened to get tenured generation filled while loadClass() does not.